# How to upload to a different drive in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a php page that lets you upload files, and the files just get uploaded to my computer, but I need them to be uploaded to a different hard drive. I need them to be uploaded to 
"D:\uploads". I know there are some other problems with this code but i just need this out of the way. Heres the code itself:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.ico.ico"/>
<?php
define("DOC_ROOT", $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/");
define("PDF_UPLOADS", DOC_ROOT."uploads/");

@$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
@$size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
@$type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
@$tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];


if (isset($name)) 
{
    if (!empty($name)) 
    {
        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, PDF_UPLOADS. $name))
            echo 'Uploaded';
        else
            echo "Not Uploaded";
    }
    else 
    {
        echo 'Please choose a file';
    }

}
?>

<form action="first.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file"><br><br>
<input type="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't it be as simple as this:

```
define("PDF_UPLOADS", "D:/uploads/");
```